# Unique Random Numbers C#

Tags: c#, wpf, random

I have a program to generate random lottery numbers in WPF but I don't know how to get unique random numbers. I got this exercise after I studied about the 'if structure' so I guess I should use that somehow but I have no idea how.

Here is my code:

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

   Random rd = new Random();

    int marginLeft = 50 + (caPaper.Children.Count * 50);

    Ellipse newBall = new Ellipse();
    newBall.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    newBall.Height = 70;
    newBall.Width = 70;
    newBall.Margin = new Thickness(marginLeft, 100, 0, 0);
    caPaper.Children.Add(newBall);

    TextBlock txt1 = new TextBlock();
    txt1.FontSize = 20;
    txt1.Foreground = Brushes.White;
    txt1.Text = " " + rd.Next(1, 45);
    Canvas.SetTop(txt1, 120);
    Canvas.SetLeft(txt1, marginLeft + 20);
    caPaper.Children.Add(txt1);
}
private void btnClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    caPaper.Children.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a method to get X random numbers?

Comment: What problem do you have with the above code?

Comment: That sometimes it generates the same number.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to generate lottery style random numers is

- Create a list of all the possible values
- Shuffle the list using a robust algorithm (e.g. [Fisher Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle))
- Take the required number of items from the front of the list